# Hide with jquery Qty field if the table row contains text

Tags: jquery, children

So I know this is a weird thing to do but I am trying to search for a phrase in a table's row "`Product Name`".
When it finds it I want to hide the field with the `title="Qty"` ( `id` can be different every time)

Here is what I tried:

```
var thebook = $("tr:contains('Product Name')");
jQuery(thebook).children(input[title='Qty']).hide();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please select the answer as correct if it works for you so that others facing same problem could also benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[title='Qty']` should be in quotes, like `"input[title='Qty']"`

Without seeing your full code, I can't be sure there aren't other problems, but here's an example of this working in which I used `.find()` rather than `.children()` to search all the way down the descendent chain:

```js
$("tr:contains('Product B')").find("input[title='Qty']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product A</td>
    <td>Quantity: <input title='Qty'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product B</td>
    <td>Quantity: <input title='Qty'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product C</td>
    <td>Quantity: <input title='Qty'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use .find() instead of .children() to search all the way down the descendent chain.

Comment: that would be more efficient approach you should update the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, @MuhammadOmerAslam - updated answer to reflect this more efficient approach.